# MySQL query with temporary column's name in Yii

Tags: php, mysql, yii, associative-array

I want to select only year from records ane make from this data assoc array

```
$wynik = $model_post::model() -> findAllBySql('SELECT DISTINCT YEAR(create_time) as rok FROM tbl_post');
for($i;$i<count($wynik);$i++)
{
    $rok[$wynik[$i]->rok]=$wynik[$i]->rok; 
}
```

but I got the exception

```
_Property "Post.rok" is not defined._
```

How can I make it correct?

Answer (score 2):

If I remember correctly this should work in Yii1 as well: define a variable `public $rok;` in your model_post class, and it will automatically be populated when you use that query.